# Orbital motion of Lissajous orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital

[Lissajous Orbit Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0GiQA_lh6Q)

In the demonstration, I do not get how is it possible for any object to orbit around the L2 point if there is no massive celestial object at the L2 point?

Comment: The short answer is that it only looks like it's orbiting around the L2 point if you start moving around in the rotating frame of the secondary body that generates the Lagrange point. Watch the excellent short video [JWST halo orbit around L2 Sun Earth](https://youtu.be/IyyQqaF4tNY) and the lovely video [lagrange points animation](https://youtu.be/z52WWLE8bBo) and read [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21234/12102) for a better explanation.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate? [What determines the orbital speed around a massless Lagrangian point?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21230/12102)